# How to do reverse image search on google by uploading image url?

Tags: python, web-scraping, google-image-search

My goal is to automate google reverse image search.

I would like to upload an image url and get all the website links that include the matching image.

So here is what I could produce so far:

```
import requests
import bs4

# Let's take a picture of Chicago
chicago = 'https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/556e10f5e4b02ae09b8ce47d/1531155504475-KYOOS7EEGVDGMMUQQNX3/ke17ZwdGBToddI8pDm48kCf3-plT4th5YDY7kKLGSZN7gQa3H78H3Y0txjaiv_0fDoOvxcdMmMKkDsyUqMSsMWxHk725yiiHCCLfrh8O1z4YTzHvnKhyp6Da-NYroOW3ZGjoBKy3azqku80C789l0h8vX1l9k24HMAg-S2AFienIXE1YmmWqgE2PN2vVFAwNPldIHIfeNh3oAGoMooVv2g/Chi+edit-24.jpg'

# And let's take google image search uploader by url
googleimage = 'https://www.google.com/searchbyimage?&image_url='

# Here is our Chicago image url uploaded into google image search
url = googleimage+chicago

# And now let's request our Chichago google image search
response = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')

# Here is the output
print(soup.prettify())
```

My problem is that I did not expect this `print(soup.prettify())`output. 
I am not including the output in the post because it's too long.

If you type in your browser:

`https://www.google.com/searchbyimage?&image_url=https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/556e10f5e4b02ae09b8ce47d/1531155504475-KYOOS7EEGVDGMMUQQNX3/ke17ZwdGBToddI8pDm48kCf3-plT4th5YDY7kKLGSZN7gQa3H78H3Y0txjaiv_0fDoOvxcdMmMKkDsyUqMSsMWxHk725yiiHCCLfrh8O1z4YTzHvnKhyp6Da-NYroOW3ZGjoBKy3azqku80C789l0h8vX1l9k24HMAg-S2AFienIXE1YmmWqgE2PN2vVFAwNPldIHIfeNh3oAGoMooVv2g/Chi+edit-24.jpg`

You will see that the html code is  way different from our output with `soup`.

I was expecting the `soup` code to have the final results so I can parse the links I need. Instead I only got some weird functions that I don't really understand.

It seems that google image search is a three step process: first you upload your image, then something happens with weird functions, then you get your final results.

How can I get my final results just like in my browser? So I can parse the html code like usual.

Comment: nice [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59176559/how-to-do-reverse-image-search-on-google-by-uploading-image-url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59176559/how-to-do-reverse-image-search-on-google-by-uploading-image-url)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me explain for you.

use `print(response.history)`
And `print(response.url`

So if it's `200`, then you will get a url such as `https://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi:`

But if it's `302`, then you will get a url such as `hhttps://www.google.com/webhp?tbs=sbi:`

For `302` that's means that Google detected you as a `BOT` and therefore it's denied you by `webhp = Web Hidden Path` which it's convert the request to for robots detection and further analyze by google side.

You can confirm that if you pressed on your link [Click Here](https://www.google.com/searchbyimage?&image_url=https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/556e10f5e4b02ae09b8ce47d/1531155504475-KYOOS7EEGVDGMMUQQNX3/ke17ZwdGBToddI8pDm48kCf3-plT4th5YDY7kKLGSZN7gQa3H78H3Y0txjaiv_0fDoOvxcdMmMKkDsyUqMSsMWxHk725yiiHCCLfrh8O1z4YTzHvnKhyp6Da-NYroOW3ZGjoBKy3azqku80C789l0h8vX1l9k24HMAg-S2AFienIXE1YmmWqgE2PN2vVFAwNPldIHIfeNh3oAGoMooVv2g/Chi%20edit-24.jpg) and check what's will appear on the browser `bar`.

[image]

> Which means that you need to consider header part in order to be on right track.

Use the following way.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {
    'Host': 'www.google.com',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Referer': 'https://www.google.com/',
    'Origin': 'https://www.google.com',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Content-Length': '0',
    'TE': 'Trailers'
}

r = requests.get("https://www.google.com/searchbyimage?image_url=https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/556e10f5e4b02ae09b8ce47d/1531155504475-KYOOS7EEGVDGMMUQQNX3/ke17ZwdGBToddI8pDm48kCf3-plT4th5YDY7kKLGSZN7gQa3H78H3Y0txjaiv_0fDoOvxcdMmMKkDsyUqMSsMWxHk725yiiHCCLfrh8O1z4YTzHvnKhyp6Da-NYroOW3ZGjoBKy3azqku80C789l0h8vX1l9k24HMAg-S2AFienIXE1YmmWqgE2PN2vVFAwNPldIHIfeNh3oAGoMooVv2g/Chi+edit-24.jpg&encoded_image=&image_content=&filename=&hl=en", headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify)
```

Comment: Indeed I do have a 302 response and it is redirecting me to `webhp` instead of `search`. So what should I do to get a 200 response instead of a 302? What should I do to my header?

Comment: I tried your code. I still have one 302 response (instead of two 302 before) in history. And when I print the `soup`. I get some weird characters and symbols. Any idea why?

Comment: @RobZ well in that case, since you tried many requests so i believe that you got blocked. i recommend tor usage with different use-agents

Comment: Do you have any resources that I can look up to in order to do that?

Comment: @RobZ you can use google image search API https://pypi.org/project/Google-Images-Search/. or `serpapi ` or `zenserp`